# Loading webpacker assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy to production (on a local machine) a Rails 5.2 app which uses webpacker for assets managemnet (I have totally replaced the assets pipeline).

Everything seems ok: as part of my deployment process I run the `webpacker:compile` task and both JS and CSS are compiled in the `public/packs` folder.

[image]

However, the assets aren't loaded from the app even if they are correctly linked.

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

I have tried to load via browser other files in the `/public` folder (i.e. `robots.txt`) but they are not availble neither. I get "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In production by default rails expects to be behind a reverse proxy server like nginx that will serve all static files from `public` more efficiently.

Also for low loads the built-in file server can be enabled as a quick-fix, in `production.rb`:

```
 config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks, I was tried the app without Nginx to make sure everything was working properly. With Nginx assets are loaded.