# Rails 6.1.1 doesn't load the webpacker created CSS files in production mode

Tags: ruby, webpacker, actiondispatch, ruby-on-rails-6.1

this is my first time asking a question here, I hope I would explain my problem well.
In one of my recent tasks, I'm upgrading our app to Ruby and Rails (Ruby 2.6.6 > 2.7.2, Rails 6.0.3.2. > 6.1.1)
I had several issues along the way, upgraded some gems and JS libraries. The application runs fine in `development` mode. However when I switch to `production` mode, I run these commands to compile and run the server.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake webpacker:compile
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js
```

When I run the app, in `production` mode it looks running normal, but when I go to `localhost:3000` it throws several `500` errors regarding to CSS files. I see the main page of the app as plain HTML, without CSS.

```
2021-01-22 11:50:51 -0500 Rack app ("GET /assets/stylesheets/app-styles-3661efb317da3fb28f52.css" - (127.0.0.1)): #<NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for #<ActionDispatch::FileHandler:0x00007ff610502c20>>
2021-01-22 11:50:25 -0500 Rack app ("GET /assets/landing.debug-05588bd014e46c264aaf6e00d2f5c570dd7ca3ed42336c2ff6d5c05bf986afe2.js" - (127.0.0.1)): #<NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for #<ActionDispatch::FileHandler:0x00007ff610502c20>>
2021-01-22 11:50:25 -0500 Rack app ("GET /assets/companyLogo-6700adf796812269b9428251803c253b9c073095ef511d3619d269a0fdd96435.png" - (127.0.0.1)): #<NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for #<ActionDispatch::FileHandler:0x00007ff610502c20>>
```

Files which are mentioned in the error are exists under the `/public` folder. In the browser's page source, I can see the path as well. When I click the folder path on page source, I see this error on the browser.
`An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`

When I check the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/FileHandler.html) of RoR, the `match?` method for `ActionDispatch::FileHandler` is not there, but in [6.0.3.2 docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.2/classes/ActionDispatch/FileHandler.html), it is deprecated without a notice, maybe.?. It is **not** something I call intentionally, it is probably called somewhere in Rails when the app is running on `production` mode.

I have those helper in my erb files.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

I tried replacing them with

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

but no luck :(

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182971/10484895) as well.

Is anyone have an idea how can I make sure Rails is loading these files and accessible in the user side? Or any better debugging suggestions are appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Note: When I switch to `development` mode, everything works fine.
BTW, Some Packages I use:

```
"@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1" #-> was 4.0.2
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2"
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "3.0.0-rc.0" #-> was 2.0.4
"webpack-cli": "4.4.0", #-> was 3.3.0 and it was only devDependency
```

Comment: Do you have log entries like this: `ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /webapp/public/packs/manifest.json`?

Comment: I had that error before I reach this point, before upgrading the `@rails/webpacker`. I tried solutions people shared online on but didn't have much luck.  So I upgraded the `@rails/webpacker` and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue with the `match?` method missing for `ActionDispatch::FileHandler`

We traced it back to: https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater/issues/54

Removing the [heroku-deflater gem](https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater) fixed it for us

Comment: Got it, thank you. I fixed that, but then I came across with `ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /webapp/public/packs/manifest.json` issue again.. I don't think I found a proper solution, did you find any solution for this, or had trouble with that error on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with this and get a error like this:

```sh
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /webapp/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-26b24ac7b08f8a1b640f.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-26b24ac7b08f8a1b640f.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-26b24ac7b08f8a1b640f.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-26b24ac7b08f8a1b640f.js.map"
      ]
    },
  }
):
```

You can resolve it by deleting the `stylesheet_pack_tag` in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**. The `javascript_pack_tag` directive loads the scss/css.
You can see in the error message `entrypoints` that the scss was not generated, its inside the js. I've self inflicted this error on me because of outdated guides.

## Example

With the following files & contents:

***app/javascript/packs/application.js***

```js
// rails generated stuff
import "styles/application.scss"
```

***app/javascript/styles/application.scss***

```css
// some scss rules
body { background-color: red; }
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while I didn't get back to this task. I tried those as a second time, but no luck, I'm still getting the same error message, besides, `You manifest contains` is empty JSON `{}`.
One of my recent finding is, when I login to Heroku instance, I see there is no `public/packs` folder, which I see it is created during deployment, then it is cleaned somehow.

Comment: And still in the heroku deployment process, heroku runs `rake assets:precompile`. Its return is `Compiled all packs in /tmp/../public/packs` however, it also asks `One CLI for webpack must be installed....Do you wanna install webpack-cli?` obviously deployment doesn't answer this. My previous version of the app runs `yarn install` with precompile comment, which install webpack-cli already, so there is no problem